# How can I find SD cards I hid

Tags: home

I had two SD cards with some personal files on them. I would normally keep them in the same discreet place, but they’re not there. I think I must have hidden them somewhere but can’t for the life of me remember 1) where that could be; 2) if I hid them to begin with.

I’ve looked everywhere in my home, including in old clothes in my wardrobe. They’re nowhere to be found. (I only found money I didn’t know I had in the pocket of a jacket.)

What can I do? My fears are 1) that somebody stole them (but who could it’ve been and when and why?!); 2) that I threw them away by mistake or vacuumed them up (but that’s unusual for two at the same time.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Lfhttyl121918, Welcome to Lifehacks. Be sure to visit [Tour] and [Help] for great information to get the most from this SE site. You know that you've moved them to a great place; but, that you've momentarily lost the coordinates. You'll find them secure where you've left them. The dilemma you will then face is whether to put them back or to put them in the place you usually put them before now. Good luck.

Comment: This is similar to losing the password for an encrypted storage volume -- in that that data is gone if you don't remember.  It's not, however, a lifehack situation.  VTC.

Comment: They're completely inert when not used and contain very little metal, so there's no way to find these things outside of an actual physical search.

Comment: Don't forget to check your card readers in case you left it inserted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tips to find misplaced keys somewhere in my house](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17764/tips-to-find-misplaced-keys-somewhere-in-my-house)

Comment: SD card and a key are the same when they're lost: you just have to look for them. No hack will help, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest several things:

1. think about where you would hide it now and go look through these
   places. It shouldn’t be like, “maybe I’d hide my SD card there”,
   it’s rather an active “I wanna hide it there, there and there”;
2. look through all card readers you have;
3. look in your wallet(s) - all pockets, small pockets in backpacks, pencil cases (or lookalikes), and small boxes with stuff;
4. if you have talked about your SD cards
   with someone before, ask them when was the last time you did it,
   where it was and what the conversation was about. Maybe you will
   remember what you did with the cards after that.

I hope you will find them.